# Invoke method in external JS file from Vue component

Tags: javascript, vue.js

I am trying to use some clustering methods in an external Javascript file I found online. The HTML example using the same JS file works (example file available in the sandbox) but I am trying to get it to work within a Vue component so that I can use it for some Vue coding

Here is some code that unfortunately breaks when I try it:

https://codesandbox.io/s/hierarchical-clustering-8t6ckt?file=/src/components/RunClustering.vue

Interestingly, when I enter the variable from the external JS file, the online editor (as well as my VSC) "sees" the variable and shows me what it can do. So there is something going on. But when I the run the code, it breaks

```
TypeError
Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'agglomerate')
```

Comment: put `export` keyword in front of `var figue`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That happens because you don't `export` the `figue` from the `Clustering.js` file, Also, there are some declaration errors in the `Clustering.js` file itself.

If fixed it all you can check [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/hierarchical-clustering-forked-6xfvr8).

Comment: Sir, you are very quick. Thanks! The online example works like a charm. I quickly copied/pasted your new code (with the revisions, thanks for catching them) but unfortunately, it doesn't work in visual studio code!                                                  
           Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: this.clus.agglomerate is not a function.                  
    at Proxy.runClu (RunClustering.vue?28ac:35:1)
    at Proxy.mounted (RunClustering.vue?28ac:53:1) grrrr

Comment: @helloworld, you are welcome, Are you sure you `copy/paste` all the code? make sure that when you import the `clus` import it like this `import clus from "./Clustering";`

Comment: Yes, I copy/paste it directly. When I add       console.log("clus.EUCLIDIAN_DISTANCE", clus.EUCLIDIAN_DISTANCE); to your code, it outputs 0 in the console. But when I d o the same in my editor, I get: undefined in the console. You can imagine that it is a bit maddening!

Comment: @helloworld Strange!, For sure there is something missing when you `copy/paste` or there is a conflict in your code.

Comment: Thanks, I checked again but there is not much room of error when doing a copy/paste. I created another question online: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73835668/invoking-external-javascript-code-works-in-codesandbox-but-not-in-visual-studio